# Assignment statement not carrying over functions python 3.1

Tags: python

I am using python 3.1 on a windows 10 device and I have ran into a problem.

When I go to use a assignment that was defined in another function that I made, the assignment does not work. My problem is in a long line of code but I made a smaller version to help explain what is happening.

```
def test():
    """ takes input """
    f = input("1 or 2? ")
    if f == 1:
        t = "wow"
    if f == 2:
        t = "woah"

def test2(t):
    """ Uses input """
    print(t)

def main():
    test()
    test2(t)

main()
input("\n\nPress enter to exit" )
```

I am not sure why the program wont use the assignment "t" after it selects an input.

My goal is to use the input from the 1st function to change the outcome of the second function. of course my original program is more complicated that a simple print function but this demonstration is what I know is messing up my program. My original program deals with opening .txt files and the input is choosing which file to open.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your code has lots of issues....`f==1` won't work because `f` is a string, how are you passing `t` to `test2()` when it isn't defined in `main()`

Comment: Use ``global t`` as the first line (after the doc) of the function-block, where you want to access the global variable ``t``. (It is only needed if you change it. => in function ``test()``)          OR           You should ``return t`` from test and assign the value to t in ``main()``.

Comment: the string part was my bad during the testing, but the passing t is what I am trying to figure out for my problem. Could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: @Collingpc you need to add the line `return t` to the end of your `test()` function, as pointed out in the answer by @paperazzo79  This allows the value of `t` to be returned to your `main()` function.  But in order to use that value of `t` in the `main()` function, you also need to change the first line of `main()` to `t=test()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to return "t" in order to use it in test2:

```
def test():
    """ takes input """
    f = input("1 or 2? ")
    if f == '1':
        t = "wow"
    if f == '2':
        t = "woah"
    return t  # This returns the value of t to main()

def test2(t):
    """ Uses input """
    print(t)

def main():
    t = test()  # This is where the returned value of t is stored
    test2(t)    # This is where the returned value of t is passed into test2()

main()
input("\n\nPress enter to exit" )
```

Comment: Don't forget to update your `if` statements to check for string values as well. They should be `if f == '1':` and `if f == '2':`

Comment: I change that and the int/string problem someone else pointed out but it still give the same error